# Java: run method based on user input?

Tags: java

say I have three methods

```
method1()
method2()
method3()
```

and I have the user input a number corresponding to which method they want to run, is there a way to run it directly from their input? i.e. instead of having an if statement along the lines of

```
System.out.println("Which method would you like to run? 1/2/3");
String input = reader.readLine();
if(input == 1){method1();}
if(input == 2){method2();}
...
```

etc. and instead be able to have something like

```
System.out.println("Which method would you like to run? 1/2/3");
String input = reader.readLine();
method(input)();
```

?

Comment: Have a look at that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string

Comment: A broader context would be helpful, because there are several drastically different approaches that could be of use to you.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you could achieve that by using an interface as follows:

```
interface A {
    void run();
}

public void method1() {}

public void method2() {}

public void mainMethod(String[] args) {
    // Initialise the method map - note, you only have to do this once
    // So, this initialisation code can go into a constructor
    // And mothodMap can be declared as a final instance variable.
    A methodOne = new A() { @Override public void run() { method1(); } };
    A methodTwo = new A() { @Override public void run() { method2(); } };

    Map<Integer, A> methodMap = new HashMap<>();
    methodMap.put(1, methodOne);
    methodMap.put(2, methodTwo);

    Integer input = /* get it from user*/ 1;
    A aMethod = methodMap.get(input);
    aMethod.run();

}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, not unless you use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). Java doesn't have function pointers, otherwise you could index to the appropriate function in an array. But what's wrong with `if` statements? They're more readable and secure..

If you're looking for a future-proof, more abstract solution, consider a [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

```
// strategy
interface CommandMethod {
    void runMethod();
}

// for every method 1 .. n
class CmdMethod1() implements CommandMethod {
    void runMethod() {
        // concrete implementation
    }
}

// initialization ----------------

Map<String, CommandMethod> cmds = new HashMap<String, CommandMethod>();
cmds.put("1", new CmdMethod1());
// .. etc ..
cmds.put("n", new CmdMethodN());

// at the prompt:
System.out.println("Which method would you like to run? 1/2/3/.../n");
String input = reader.readLine();

cmds.get(input).runMethod(); // more like what you're going for ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Not without having an if or switch statement (or reflection like paislee pointed out). If you wanted to do something like `method(input);` you would need the if/switch statement in another method:

```
    ....
    String input = reader.readLine();
    method(input);
}

private void method(int input) {
    if (input == 1) {method1();}
    if (input == 2) {method2();}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this. However, you can use if-statements or switch-case statements to make the "redirection" process less cumbersome. You might also consider creating a wrapper function to accept the user input to make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of accomplishing this is to create a "functor"

```
public interface Functor
{
    public void execute();
}

public class Method1 implements Functor
{
    public void execute() { /* do something */ }
}

etc...


private Functor[] f = { new Method1(), new Method2(), new Method3() };

...

// Execute the method selected by i
f[i].execute();
```

Also take a look at the `Callable` interface

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this. Another way this can be implemented is by using switch-case in a while true loop. And using scanner object `static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);` user input.

```
while(true){
  System.out.print("Input: ");
  int option = scanner.nextInt();
  switch(option){
    case 1 -> method1();
    case 2 -> method2();
  }
}
```

do remember to include a way to exit the while loop in any of the methods.